# How to expand a tree panel when page is loaded - EXTJS 4

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4

```
var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        store: store,
        rootVisible: false,
        //useArrows: true,
        frame: true,
        title: 'Vehicle List',
        region:'west',
        width: 200,
        root: {
        expanded: true
        },
        checked : false,
        height: 250,
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            items: {
                text: 'Get checked nodes',
                handler: function(){
                    var records = tree.getView().getChecked(),
                        names = [];

                    Ext.Array.each(records, function(rec){
                        names.push(rec.get('MainID'));
                    });

                    Ext.MessageBox.show({
                        title: 'Selected Nodes',
                        msg: names.join('<br />'),
                        icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO
                    });
                }
            }
        }]
    });
```

How can I get the tree to expand? I have tried

```
root: {
        expanded: true
        }
```

But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your model:

```
{ name: 'expanded', type: 'boolean', defaultValue: true, persist: false },
```

Or alternatively set `expanded` to true for each  node you return from the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
root: {
        expanded: true
      }
```

This should be within the definition of your store.

Something like the below.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        children: [
            { text: "a", leaf: true },
            { text: "b", expanded: true, children: [
                { text: "c", leaf: true },
                { text: "d", leaf: true}
            ] }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: If the down-voter adds the comment, it would be appreciated. This is not like taking away my money. This is a community. It will help others

Comment: i don't know why someone voted this down. Better answer than the accepted answer I think